# SQL Query to Get Individual values from accumulated data

Tags: sql

The below sample data has a cumulative size for each entry. I am trying to write a query to update the size, with the difference in size with the previous timestamp(For example - row 2 should be updated with (4478.74 - 4476) = 2.74) for the same item name. Please help me on this one.

```
Row Item     Size       Time
-----------------------------------------------
1   ItemA    4476       7/01/2012 11:15
2   ItemA    4478.74    7/01/2012 11:20
3   ItemA    4478.82    7/01/2012 11:21
4   ItemA    4487.51    7/01/2012 11:29
5   ItemB    1.53       7/01/2012 11:29
6   ItemB    1.67       7/01/2012 11:20
7   ItemB    1.84       7/01/2012 11:21
8   ItemB    2.18       7/01/2012 11:15
```

Comment: You don't say what should happen for the first row -- the first time an Item is represented in the table.  I'm guessing you want it left unchanged.

Comment: Your data is out of order -- row 8 is earlier than row 5-7.  Is this intentional?  Do you really want to start off w/ row 8 as the "first" ItemB entry.

Comment: Which SQL... SQL-Server, MySQL, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can partition the data by Item and then outer join it to itself on the previous row number:

```
    create table ItemTotal (id uniqueidentifier, item varchar(10), size numeric(10,2), entry datetime)

    insert into ItemTotal values(NEWID(), 'ItemA', 4476, '7/01/2012 11:15');
    insert into ItemTotal values(NEWID(), 'ItemA', 4478.74, '7/01/2012 11:20');
    insert into ItemTotal values(NEWID(), 'ItemA', 4478.82, '7/01/2012 11:21');
    insert into ItemTotal values(NEWID(), 'ItemA', 4487.51, '7/01/2012 11:29');
    insert into ItemTotal values(NEWID(), 'ItemB', 1.53, '7/01/2012 11:29');
    insert into ItemTotal values(NEWID(), 'ItemB', 1.67, '7/01/2012 11:20');
    insert into ItemTotal values(NEWID(), 'ItemB', 1.84, '7/01/2012 11:21');
    insert into ItemTotal values(NEWID(), 'ItemB', 2.18, '7/01/2012 11:15');

    with items(id, item, size, entry, rn) as (
    select id, item, size, entry, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (Partition By item order by entry) as rn From ItemTotal t)
    select i.item, i.size, i.entry, i.size - coalesce(o.size, 0) as difference
    from items i
    left outer join items o on o.item = i.item and o.rn = i.rn-1
    order by i.item, i.entry desc
```

Resulting Output:

```
item    size    entry   difference
ItemA   4487.51 2012-07-01 11:29:00.000 8.69
ItemA   4478.82 2012-07-01 11:21:00.000 0.08
ItemA   4478.74 2012-07-01 11:20:00.000 2.74
ItemA   4476.00 2012-07-01 11:15:00.000 4476.00
ItemB   1.53    2012-07-01 11:29:00.000 -0.31
ItemB   1.84    2012-07-01 11:21:00.000 0.17
ItemB   1.67    2012-07-01 11:20:00.000 -0.51
ItemB   2.18    2012-07-01 11:15:00.000 2.18
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is out of order.  Row 8 is earlier than rows 5-7.  I'm guessing that you want to start off w/ the earliest and go from there.

So, assuming a table definition of:

```
create table ItemTotal (itemTotalId int, item varchar(10), size numeric(10,2), 
                        entry datetime, sizeDifferential numeric(10,2));
```

The following joins to itself twice to find the most recent previous timestamp of the same Item Type.  Thus this ignores rownumber which is in general a good RDBMS practice.  (I'm not sure if it's actually part of the table, or just an identifier in your question.)

```
update ItemTotal 
set newSize = coalesce((size - 
                  (select size 
                   from ItemTotal IT2
                   where ItemTotal.item = IT2.item
                     and IT2.entry < ItemTotal.entry
                     and not exists (select * from ItemTotal IT3
                                     where IT2.item = IT3.item
                                       and IT3.entry > IT2.entry
                                       and IT3.entry < ItemTotal.entry)
                   )
           ), size);
```

This particular way to do the join finds a row w/ a previous time, where there does not exist another row that is more recent then the IT2 row selected, but is less than the source ItemTable row.

You could also write this the most inner query using a max(entry) -- it's not clear which will be faster.

The output from this is:

```
    ITEM    SIZE    ENTRY                       NEWSIZE
1   ItemA   4476    July, 01 2012 11:15:00-0700 4476
2   ItemA   4478.74 July, 01 2012 11:20:00-0700 2.74
3   ItemA   4478.82 July, 01 2012 11:21:00-0700 0.08
4   ItemA   4487.51 July, 01 2012 11:29:00-0700 8.69
5   ItemB   1.53    July, 01 2012 11:29:00-0700 -0.31
6   ItemB   1.67    July, 01 2012 11:20:00-0700 -0.51
7   ItemB   1.84    July, 01 2012 11:21:00-0700 0.17
8   ItemB   2.18    July, 01 2012 11:15:00-0700 2.18
```

If you ran this directly updating size, you could obviously only run it once.  For one-time only updates, I'd prefer to update into a temporary table/column, verify results and then reflect back into the original column.

Note:  A correlated self-join in an update like this will fail in a few dbs (mysql), but works in most others (MSSQL, for example).